# Closing an EntityManager doesnt put the connection back to the connection Pool

Tags: spring

I was trying a very simple example of explicit database commit in a spring boot application. (Didnt want to use the Transactiontemplate ).

I am trying to explicitly create an `EntityManager` from the `EntityManagerFactory` and then use the `EntityTransaction` `begin` and `commit`.
When I close the `EntityManager` , the connection doesn't go back to the connection pool.
After a maximum of 10 inserts, I get error, couldnt get JDBC connection.
What is causing this problem, any idea ?

Java version 1.8 , DB = mysql
The code snippet and the pom xml is given below.

Thanks

Srini

The ServiceImpl class

```
@Component
public class ServiceImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    
    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void monitorSch() throws InterruptedException {
        int iCnt = 0;
        do {
            iCnt++;
            insertData();
        }while (iCnt < 50);
    }
    
    public void insertData () {
        EntityManager em1 = em.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction ex = em1.getTransaction();
        ex.begin();
        Query qry = em1.createNativeQuery(" insert into test_util values (?1, ?2, ?3)") ;
        qry.setParameter(1, counter.incrementAndGet());
        qry.setParameter(2, "abcd");
        qry.setParameter(3,  new Date());
        int rows = qry.executeUpdate();
        ex.commit();
        em1.close();
        System.out.println (" rows " + rows);
        
    }
}
```

and my Main class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan
public class SpringTransApplication {
    
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTransApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The pom xml contains the following dependency

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>trimarkgaming</groupId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- The Spanner JDBC driver dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>`
```

Comment: Don't close it as that will break things. Your method should use proper Spring managed transactions. For this use the transaction template (if you want explicit control) and the injected `EntityManager`. Also you are using Spring Boot remove all annotations from the `@SpringBootAPplication` class except `@SpringBootApplication` and `@EnableScheduling`. Finally remove the `spring-context-support` dependency, that isn't needed and already pulled in from other dependencies.